# I want to group executables of rust with attributes as cargo build --release

Tags: rust

I've made the following configuration and I can successfully make executables called `media` and `strings`. Moreover I want to make executables of media.rs and str.rs. Is it possible to do?

Concretely, I desire executables which are named with `media/image`, `strings/parse` so that I can group executables with some attributes.

```sh
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
└── src
    └── bin
        ├── media
        │   ├── image.rs
        │   └── main.rs
        └── strings
            ├── main.rs
            └── parse.rs
```

[This official document](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/project-layout.html) implies that I may can't achieve what I want to do though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cargo/Rust does not have a built-in way for you to do this. However, you can use [cargo-make](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-make). Similar to `cargo clippy` or `cargo fmt`, `cargo-make` is an extension to the `cargo` command that gives you access to `cargo make`. It can be installed with `cargo install` (The `--force` just tells it to overwrite any previous version of `cargo-make`).

> `cargo install --force cargo-make`

You can batch together building multiple crates, binaries, or arbitrary shell commands. The main benefit it has over something like a traditional `Makefile` is it is cross-platform and is optimized so it will build multiple crates at the same time when possible. After installing it with `cargo make [task]`. Here is an example from their docs of what a `Makefile.toml` could look like:

```
[tasks.format]
install_crate = "rustfmt"
command = "cargo"
args = ["fmt", "--", "--emit=files"]

[tasks.clean]
command = "cargo"
args = ["clean"]

[tasks.build]
command = "cargo"
args = ["build"]
dependencies = ["clean"]

[tasks.test]
command = "cargo"
args = ["test"]
dependencies = ["clean"]

[tasks.my-flow]
dependencies = [
    "format",
    "build",
    "test"
]
```